# Linux: Can't overwrite files on samba store

Tags: windows, linux, permissions, samba, centos

I'm using CentOS 5.5 with `smbclient 3.0.33-3.28-el5` (latest version in repo), and I can't overwrite files in my Samba store.

I am not the admin for the Windows server that hosts the share, so there isn't anything I can do server side.  But I do have write permission to the server.  I know the server runs Windows XP or Server 2003; I don't know which.
I can delete the file, and then copy the new version over, but I can't overwrite it.

Using the `cp` command I'll get this error:

```
[jonescb@localhost ~]$ cp foo.txt /mnt/si_storage/foo.txt
cp: cannot create regular file `/mnt/si_storage/foo.txt': No such file or directory`
```

And if I edit a file on the server using vim, I can save it once, but if I save it again I get this:
`"/mnt/si_storage/foo.txt" E212: Can't open file for writing`

This is my /etc/fstab entry for the samba server:
`//192.168.1.2/SI_STORAGE    /mnt/si_storage cifs    username=myuser,password=mypass    0 0`

Edit: I can overwrite files just fine on my XP machine.  The CentOS box is the only one having problems.

Comment: Reading this makes me very confused. A Windows XP or 2003 system is running Samba? Do you mean SMB services (Windows Share)? Just where does "my Samba store" exist, on Windows or CentOS? Is your CentOS system trying to mount its own Samba share?

Comment: Yes, it's a Windows Share.  I just have the habit of calling it Samba.  The CentOS box doesn't host any SMB shares, it's only mounting one from a Windows server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by adding nodfs to the mount options.
I found it here http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/dsn323-samba-dfs-bug/start.

It says that nodfs was added in linux 2.6.28, but it looks like Red Hat backported it to their 2.6.18 kernel.

Comment: Or that RedHat invented it.